# How to find IP address of a validator in BSC network

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc, enode

In Binance Smart Chain(BSC) there are validator nodes, and mining is not enabled. BSC uses go-ethereum fork, is there any way to find the IP addresses of these validator nodes? I wonder where on the earth they are mostly located.